# Add a nill value before populating block with district,and so on with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a code which populates **block** when **district** is selected.

But, I want to add this

`<option value=''>Select</option>`

before populating the block with values

**Example :-**

*Before Selecting District*

```
District
<option>Dist 1</option>
<option>Dist 2</option>
<option>Dist 3</option>
<option>Dist 4</option>

Block
<option>Select District First</option>
```

*After Selecting district*

```
District
<option>Dist 2</option>
//Other District options are available here

Block
<option>Select Block</option>  //I want to add this option
<option>Block 1 for District 2</option>
<option>Block 2 for District 2</option>
<option>Block 3 for District 2</option>
```

So, when the user selects a different block from the list of Ajax sent data, there will be a blank option. Once the block is changed, other options (relating to `onchange` of block will be changed)

Here is my code

**Ajax**

```
 
  $('#district').on('change',function(){
   var district = $('#district').val();
 
     //console.log("State Name for Country",countryname);

       if(!district){
         return;
       }
       $.ajaxSetup({
           headers: {
               'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
           }
           });  
                $.ajax({
                       type:'GET',
                       url: 'get-block?district='+district,
                       success:function(response){
                         // console.log(response);
                         if(response){
                            
                           $("#block").empty();
                           
                           
                            $.each(response,function(key,value){
                             
                               $("#block").append('<option value="'+value+'">'+key+'</option>');
                               });
                         }
                     },
  
                }); //ajax ends
   
    });
```

**HTML Blade**

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
                   <label>District</label>
                   <select class="form-control" id="district" name="district">
                      <option value="">Select</option>
                      @foreach($district as $district)
                        <option value="{{$district->TDM_Dist_Code}}">{{$district->TDM_Dist_Name}}</option>
                      @endforeach
                   </select>
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                   <label>Block</label>
                   <select class="form-control" id="block" name="block">
                      <option value="" id="after_block">Select</option>
                   </select>
                </div>
```

Comment: do you just want to clear the blocks list when you are changing the district?

Comment: @RahulR. Yes. Clear the block list after District is changed. But there should be an option with null value in block list

Comment: Hi, simply use `$("#block").append("<option value=''>Select</option>")` after emptying your select-box

Comment: @Swati But, how to populate the rest of the data with blocks? Meaning, there should be a '` '` value (with Select option) and the rest will be `blocks` against a particular district.

Comment: do you want to keep that null value in block list always? I mean during the district change also?

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the content of select as below:

```
$("#block").empty();
```

then while populating the new values for a district simply use :

```
$("#block").append("<option value=''>Select</option>");
```

to append a empty option with.

So your code would look something like this:

```
$('#district').on('change', function () {
    var district = $('#district').val();

    //console.log("State Name for Country",countryname);

    if (!district) {
        return;
    }
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    //Just before making ajax empty the select list, 
    // with this if your ajax fails, you wont have wrong data against district.
    $("#block").empty();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'get-block?district=' + district,
        success: function (response) {
            // console.log(response);
            if (response) {

                $("#block").append("<option value=''>Select</option>");

                $.each(response, function (key, value) {
                    $("#block").append('<option value="' + value + '">' + key + '</option>');
                });
            }
        },

    }); //ajax ends

});
```